# Publish Profile not deploying on TFS Build

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a .net4 solution in VS2012 that has a website with its own publishprofile.

The profile successfully publishes via webdeploy when executed from within VS, but when using a TFS2012 build it seems to get ignored.

I pass these MSBuild arguments into the build:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:PublishProfile=CI /p:Configuration=CI /p:UserName=XXX /p:Password=XXXXXX
```

I thought DeployOnBuild=true would force MSBuild to execute the publish profiles of the same name within the solution.

Is this not the case?

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed on the build machine? You can also add /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 to the MSBuild args to make sure you are resolving the right targets.

Comment: `/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0` param helped me to resolve the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question in my search. 
When you have created a publish profile (in your case, called "CI"), it is saved into an xml file in the properties section of the project, with the extension ".pubxml".

So as an answer to your question, you should replace the /p:PublishProfile=CI part with /p:PublishProfile=CI.pubxml.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use this arguments for the msbuild.

> /p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true

In this case, it generates a Package folder with the project that it has the website.