# TFS Build unable to PUBLISH

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have recently set up Automated builds using TFS Build 2012. I have different web servers where I want to publish my application. I have:

1) A build server.
2) DB Server
3) WebServer1 (Web Deploy Agent Installed)
4) WebServer2 (Web Deploy Agent Installed)
5) WebServer3 (Which is the same on which I have set up TFSBuild i.e. build Controller and Agents)

Now when ever I Publish my application manually using RightClick->Publish(Publish Method= Web Deploy) from VisualStudio it is successfully deployed to all the webservers.

Similarly when I QUE a build using TFS Build for WebServer3 (which has BuildController and agent on it) it works fine.

But when I try to do the same for WebServer1 or WebServer2 it just compiles the code and DONT publish anything on server. The worst thing is that it it NOT giving me any error as well. It says Build was deployed Successfully.

I have tried solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423500/publish-profile-not-deploying-on-tfs-build/) but its not working :(

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My MSBuild arguments are as follows:

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:PublishProfile=Application 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl="https://WebServer3" 
/t:Build;Publish  
/p:SqlPublishProfilePath=DB.publish.xml
```

I have explicitly asked set **/p:DeployOnBuild=True**  but even then its not publishing.

However like I explained earlier it deploy successfully for the sever on which I have installed the build controller and agents.

Is there any requirement that for every webserver you must install the build controller and agents. I dont think its a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I figured out what was wrong.

The problem was that there was no ***Build Controller Agent*** Installed on **WebServer1** and **WebServer2** due to which the TFS build was unable to transfer my build to that server. But there ***MUST***  be some error for this.

I tried it after installing the build controller agent on webserver1 and webserver2 and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

We worked a whole chapter in the [Build Customization Guidance](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com): "Deployment of Applications and Data Stores".

Create a Build Definition for each web server and set the correct value for

> MSDeployServiceUrl

This is the address of the remote agent service installed in the Web Deploy. Using this URL the Web Deploy will be contacted to publish the application.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an appropriate answer.

Comment: Then add details to your question, specifically the customizations you made to the Default Build Template, and your security configuration

Comment: I did not make any customization in the Default Build Template... I am going to add my MSBuild parameter in the question for further clarification.
My problem is just that it compiles everything but do not PUBLISH it.

Comment: Good you add more info.
So you are not explicitly addressing WebServer3 in the parameters, so it must be implicitly stated in the Publishing profile.
This way you cannot deploy to more than one server: or you customize the Build Template or you use a "replicating" mechanism like the Web Farm Framework or you put the site on a network share. Choose one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for some confusion. Actually my WebServer3 = MSBuildServer. I have edited the original post as well. After your last comment I guess I made a little confusion with scenario, I dont want to replicate my one build on 3 servers at the same time. These are different servers maintained to different purposes you can assume one server for QA, one server for Live Client etc. I hope I have added some more clarity now.

Comment: In the guide it is explained how to publish on a specific server, *but* as I wrote before, you cannot publish more then once per build. What you can do is to have three Build Definitions, each publishing to a different server.

Comment: yes you are correct and I have done it the same way. I am just not sure about one thing "What software or configurations I need to make to any web server where I want to publish my builds using TFS build? Is it mandatory to install Build Controller on every web server or just one Build controller can work for remote web servers?" thanks

Comment: I did *your* homework and extracted the snippet of information you need.